# How to build a configuration with templates/blockinfile/lineinfile in a modular manner

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to assemble an iptables file suitable for iptables-restore using multiple roles:

- There's a role `setup-iptables` that creates an initial file containing some common rules (i.e. allowing SSH). The file is created from a big template.
- There're multiple smaller roles, that add to this file (i.e. `setup-httpd` adds rules for ports 80 and 443).

Playbooks are supposed to import the role `setup-iptables` first and then import the smaller roles that are needed to configure the host.

My problem is, that this file gets recreated every time the playbook is run. This is potentially dangerous if the play gets interupted and the incomplete rules get applied. Also it's ugly because ansible will show changes to the host, even if the resulting file is identical to its original state.

Simply working with `lineinfile` and `blockinfile` from the beginnning is not an option because the iptable rules are highly dependend on the ordering of the rules. The initial template is required because it provides a lot of 'markers'. These markers are then used by the `lineinfile` statements of the subsequent roles to corretly position their rules.

My current workaround idea is to assemble the file locally and at the end of the play 'flush' it to the remote host.

Is there a better way? What's the 'ansible way' to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the file exists and if it does, skip recreating it...

```
- name: check if the file exists
  stat:
    path: /etc/sysconfig/iptables #Example path
  register: iptables_file

- name: Create the file if it doesnt exists
  copy:
    content: "your initial rules"
    dest: /etc/sysconfig/iptables
  when: iptables_file.stat.exists == False
```

Comment: But then changes to the base template won't be applied to the host.

Comment: After you check if it exists and the file already there, you just write the base template... After you do that, if you run the playbook again it wont overwrite the file, just will add the lines it does not have on it... For writing you base lines, you can use the lineinfile and for the remaining roles, you can use the "insertafter" parameter...

Comment: You mean: Make the base template almost empty or even a static file and then add the base parts by lineinfile etc....? That might work, although it'll be really finnicky. Thanks.

Comment: The `stat` task is unnecessary. Setting `force=false` on the `copy` task has the same effect.